# Удаление дублей символа из строки

Tags: sql, oracle

Нашел запрос - как оставить цифры и точки, но две точки по прежнему будут мешать, чтобы строку конвертировать в число (нужна только одна).

Как элегантно удалить все точки после первой?

Сейчас:

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT '#2 apps(0_-ORACLE+*.ru_ )ПРИ.13мер' Str FROM Dual)
SELECT Str,
  Regexp_Replace(Str, '[^[:digit:].]') AS Only_Number
FROM t;
```

Результат:

> 20..13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поделить строку по первой найденой точке на на две части, результаты соединить в один:

```sql
with t as (
    select '#2 apps(0_-ORACLE+*.ru_ )ПРИ.13мер' Str from dual
)
select 
    regexp_replace (substr (str, 1, instr (str, '.')),  '[^0-9.]+')|| 
    regexp_replace (substr (str, instr (str, '.') + 1), '[^0-9]+' ) res
from t
;
```

Результат:

> 20.13

Не стоит забывать о квантификаторах, в данном случае `+`. Функция `regexp_replace` по-умолчанию замещает все найденные подстроки. В данном случае, без `+`  подстроки будут состоять из отдельных символов, или другими словами, будет выполнен цикл по каждому найденному символу.